# dragover and drop event not support in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

My drag and drop event seems to be working fine in firefox, but not in IE10. Can someone suggest why, and how to fix it?

HTML :

```
<div class="drop">
  Drop file here
</div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj1 = $('.drop');
  obj1.on('dragover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', "2px solid #8e44ad");
  });
  obj1.on('drop', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', "2px solid #8e44ad");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. this is support for IE10.
remove `var obj1 = $('.drop');` and use directly on drop,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.drop').on('dragover', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css('border', "2px solid #8e44ad");
      });
      $('.drop').on('drop', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css('border', "2px solid #8e44ad");
      });
    });
```